# imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:) Xcode 7 Swift Error

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, xcode7

The image picker delegate is not compiling in Xcode 7. It is still compiling in Xcode 6.4.

I have Xcode Version 7.0 beta 3 (7A152u)

Is there a new way to declare the function in Xcode 7?  This is how I am using it in the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, 
                      UITableViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, 
                      UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController(
            picker: UIImagePickerController,
            didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error? maybe something have been added and you are using newly added method which is unknown for SDK in version 8

Comment: This is the error: Objective-C method `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` provided by method `imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)` conflicts with optional requirement method `imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)` in protocol `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
func imagePickerController(
        picker: UIImagePickerController, 
        didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    // code
}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked!. How did you know that `AnyObject` has changed to `String` though?

Comment: It is in the updated documentation. Also, code completion is your friend ;-)

Comment: Code completion didn't work. It was the flrst thing that i've tried. Also it seems I am looking at the wrong documentation because it shows AnyObject. Thanks tough! I'll be more careful.